# How to change the number in the URL inside the for loop C#

Tags: c#, string, url

I need help with changing the number in the URL inside the for loop.

Let me give an example:

- `https://www.....com/page1`
- `https://www.....com/page2`
- ...
- `https://www.....com/page7649`

I want to increase this page number. As far as I know, it is necessary to convert the url to a string. After editing this string, it is necessary to convert the string back to url.
Do I have any chance to increase it by assigning an integer inside the url?

Also if this url is given as kind of `https://www.***.com/page2a=+w4ytq`, do we need another way to solve this problem?

Comment: Please share with us your code, which shows how did you try to tackle this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an interpolated string:

```
int pageCount = 500;
for (int pageIndex = 0; pageIndex++; pageIndex < pageCount) {
    string url = $"https://www..com/page{pageIndex + 1}";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that it would be simple counter to increase the string number. See if below works for you

```
public static void Main (string[] args) 
{
   int pagenum = 0;
   string url = "https://www.Google.com/page"; //input URL as string for test
   Uri newURI = new Uri(url); // Converts string to URL for test

   string urltoString = newURI.ToString(); // Converts URL to string for changing text
   int maxpagenum = 10; // Maximum number of pages
   for (int i =0; i<=maxpagenum;i++)
   {
     pagenum = i;
     string newURL = urltoString+pagenum.ToString(); //Creates new string with page number
     Uri uri = new Uri(newURL); // Converts string to URL
     Console.WriteLine(uri); // Prints URL
   }
    
   Console.WriteLine("End");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the page number out of the url and append it in your for loop.

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string baseurl = "https://www.{}.com/page";
        uint maxpage = 7649; // Insert right number
        for (uint page = 0; page < maxpage; ++page) 
        {
            string url = baseurl + page; // + "a=+w4ytq";
        }       
    }
}
```

If you first need to obtain the baseurl from a full url, use a regular expression to retrieve the string before the first digit:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
(...)
string baseurl = Regex.Match(fullurl, @"^[^0-9]*").Value;
```

Regarding your second question:

- The regex still works like a charm
- Uncomment `+ "a=+w4ytq";`

Comment: "Also if this url is given as kind of https://www.***.com/page2a=+w4ytq, do we need another way to solve this problem?"

Can you define this problem more precisely? Should `a=+w4yt` always be added after the page number?

Comment: yes, I meant that the number is changed between "https://www.***.com/page" and  "a=+w4yt"